# Load balancing php daemons

Tags: php, process

Have 4 servers, and have 4 php daemons for broadcasting sms notifications. But at the moment all load is in first server, and i do not find solution to split load balancing on php daemons on every server. In case when 1 server is down, All the load was distributed between 3 servers.

Part of the script code

```
while (true)
{
    $params = array('limit' => $limitRecords);
    
    $requests = $request->getRequests($params);
    
    if (!$requests)
    {
        sleep(3);
    }
    else
    {
        $requestsTotal = count($requests);
        
        foreach ($requests as $req)
        {
            $cmdNewProcess = "/usr/bin/php " . __DIR__  . "/request_sender.php " . $req['phone_number'] . " " . $req['notification_text'];
            exec($cmdNewProcess . " > /dev/null &");
        }
        
        sleep($sleepInterval);
    }
}
```

Comment: all the servers have different IP addresses presumably so set the DNS to do `round-robin`?

Comment: Yes all servers have different IP addresses, and daemons are running at the server which have virtual IP

Comment: Can you explain your configuration in a bit more detail please. You say the daemons are broadcasting SMS notifications - how does each daemon get its data?

Comment: Have a table with prepared sms notifications ~2000-3000 rows. PHP daemon run with supervisor, and in daemon script have a loop, which everytime check this table on available rows for broadcasting. I will update question and will share part of code.